# conda env: using latex in matplotlib

Tags: python, latex, conda

Latex doesn't find the os library when used from my conda environment.

For example after a source of my conda environment 

`source activate myenv`

the command `latex` returns

`` latex: ~/anaconda2/lib/libtiff.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.58)
latex: ~anaconda2/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.58) ``

Does Latex need to be installed as conda package?

Comment: operating system? how did you install latex?

Comment: operating system is ubuntu 16.04. Latex was installed via the official ubuntu package and it is working when used without my conda environment activated.